# How i can search a mysql column table for specific text with doublequotes

Tags: mysql, search

I want to make a search in a table column for this text: `"value": ""`
The type of the column is **longtext**. Whatever i tried returned no results. Please help me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Select * from SomeTable Where SomeColumn Like '%"value": ""%'
```

Should work, if it jibs at the double quotes then escape the quotes like this:

```
Select * from SomeTable Where SomeColumn Like "%\"value\": \"\"%"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use escaped quotes: \".

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from table Where yourcol = '"value": ""'
```